# Is it possible to use a custom sidebar per post in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, sidebar

Is it possible to use custom sidebar per post in Wordpress without coding it into the template?

I attempted to use the Flexible Posts Widget plugin but it didn't work properly.

Comment: No you have to code in single.php with if else, or you can make a custom sidebar that accept the post id as argument and return sidebar related to that post id@SaifulIslamsaifultech

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that sidebar doesn't already exist, you would need to register_sidebar(), 
and then to get_sidebar( string $name = null ) within specific template. 
But if same sidebar appears on other pages, and you just need to restrict visibility per post for specific widget, 
try with widget visibility related plugins, i.e. 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-visibility-without-jetpack/ 
or 
https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-visibility/ 
Figure what's more appropriate for your needs. 
You will get "visibility" button for each widget, and then you can set for which post to appear.